# eval error when load from database

Tags: php, mysql, eval

This is my code;

```
$script = $row['script']; 

   // $row is from database and the $row['script'] is exeactly the same with $script commented below.
  // $script ="global \$timedate;\$target =\$timedate->now();return \$target;";

return eval($script);
```

When I uncomment the $script, it will run correctly. However, if  I commnent $script and load the value from $row['script'], the eval get error below:

```
 [12-May-2012 22:09:25 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\Users\iopen\Documents\IOPEN\Project\Clients\sugarcrm\hfcrmlocal\custom\modules\iopenwf\model\IOpenAction.php(56) : eval()'d code on line 3
```

Any idea?

Comment: what is the content of $script variable?

Comment: $script ="global \$timedate;\$target =\$timedate->now();return \$target;"

Comment: It can't be exactly the same. Maybe the db contains a literal backslash before the `$` signs, while on the PHP string the backslashes are escape characters?

Comment: _eval()'d code on line 3_ ... I don't see any line 3 in your above-mentioned comment.

Comment: I tried to use "global v_timedate;v_target =v_timedate--now();return \$target;" in the database, and I use $script=str_replace("v_","\\$",$script);$script=str_replace("--","->",$script);  It get the same error.

Comment: But that's still inserting a literal backslash into `$script`...

Comment: Line3: that is because I stored it in database as multiple lines before. However, when I changed to 1 line , it get the same error  eval()'d code on line 1.

Comment: Just remove the literal backslashes.

Comment: why would you EVER need to store code in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `eval` its a very bad idea.

For experimenting purpose you can use `stripslashes` to remove most slashes issues

```
class Test {
    function now() {
        return time ();
    }
}

$timedate = new Test ();
$script = "global \$timedate;\$target =\$timedate->now();return \$target;";
$script = stripslashes ( $script );
var_dump ( eval ( $script ) );
```

Comment: I tried the code like this:                                     $script = $row['script'];$script = stripslashes ( $script );
return  var_dump (eval ( $script ));                                and I get error:[12-May-2012 22:45:39 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in C:\Users\iopen\Documents\IOPEN\Project\Clients\sugarcrm\hfcrmlocal\custom\modules\iopenwf\model\IOpenAction.php(54) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Am sure the new error has something to do with the class you are calling ... can u you my own class also put the content of the database in pastebin let us see ..

Comment: if i run code below, it will sucess:                             $script ="global \$timedate;\$target =\$timedate->now();return \$target;";
return eval($script);  
but failed for
$script = $row['script']; 
return eval($script);

Comment: global $timedate; is from sugarcrm. This one should be ok as i use it somewhere else a lot.

Comment: Sorry, it not working for "return \$target = 'High';" either in database.  I will continue late this evening.

Comment: I just was the raw data so that I can test myself

Answer (score 0):

Try making a function of your script, it'll make it easier to edit later and you will have a better overview. 
As you can probly see, I remove the eval(); function. Now it does the job. I'm not sure why you needed eval() but with the script below, there's no eval(); needed.

```
<?php
   function getScript() {
      $script = 1;  
      // $row is from database and the $row['script'] is exeactly the same with $script commented below.
      // $script ="global \$timedate;\$target =\$timedate->now();return \$target;";
      return $script;
      }
   $scriptNo = getScript();
   echo $scriptNo;
?>
```

Comment: if i run code below, it will sucess:                             $script ="global \$timedate;\$target =\$timedate->now();return \$target;";
return eval($script);  
but failed for
$script = $row['script']; 
return eval($script);